# Lambda node.js HTTP Request that returns value

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-web-services, lambda

New to node.js and Lambda. I am working on an Alexa Skill. I have a single string stored in a file on a web server.

I am looking for an example of code that does an HTTP request and returns the value.

Example web server at : http://www.shafer.ca/percent

Seems like it should be very easy, but I cannot seem to find an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a basic http get request, which gets some data from the server.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "port": "3000",
  "path": "/",
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.end();
```

i hope this helps

Comment: FWW for this chunk to work with the OP's example web server... _hostname_ should be `"www.shafer.ca"` and _path_ should be `"/percent"`.

Comment: Thanks. I get the error message {
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'handler' missing on module 'index'"
}

Comment: Logs: START RequestId: df568dbb-3ad7-11e6-9d5d-a1ecff366d04 Version: $LATEST
Handler 'handler' missing on module 'index'
2016-06-25T13:22:32.533Z df568dbb-3ad7-11e6-9d5d-a1ecff366d04 0.49%
END RequestId: df568dbb-3ad7-11e6-9d5d-a1ecff366d04
REPORT RequestId: df568dbb-3ad7-11e6-9d5d-a1ecff366d04 Duration: 253.94 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 16 MB